# Trouble Installing jupyter with Python 3.8 on Windows 10 VM

Tags: python, jupyter, python-3.8

Perhaps somebody can help out.  I'm having trouble installing jupyter on a Windows 10 VM hosted on a mac.  Python version is 3.8.2

I've tried within the Windows VM:

```
 pip install jupyter
 pip install notebook
 pip install jupyterlab
```

Basically all variants.  :).  Anyhow, there seems to be an SSL error going on that I cannot deduce.  Any help appreciated.  Stack Trace posted below.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Jeff H\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o1ayeuqg\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Jeff H\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o1ayeuqg\\pywinpty\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Jeff H\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o1ayeuqg\pywinpty\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\Jeff H\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o1ayeuqg\pywinpty\
Complete output (83 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1230, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1276, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1225, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1004, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 944, in send
    self.connect()
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1399, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 766, in open_url
    return open_with_auth(url, self.opener)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 961, in _socket_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 1080, in open_with_auth
    fp = opener(request)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1362, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1322, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jeff H\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o1ayeuqg\pywinpty\setup.py", line 68, in <module>
    setup(
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 716, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 786, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 665, in easy_install
    dist = self.package_index.fetch_distribution(
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 655, in fetch_distribution
    dist = find(requirement)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 635, in find
    loc = self.download(dist.location, tmpdir)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 579, in download
    found = self._download_url(scheme.group(1), spec, tmpdir)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 824, in _download_url
    return self._attempt_download(url, filename)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 830, in _attempt_download
    headers = self._download_to(url, filename)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 729, in _download_to
    fp = self.open_url(url)
  File "c:\users\jeff h\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package_index.py", line 779, in open_url
    raise DistutilsError("Download error for %s: %s"
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Download error for https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/ad/9ebf6d2edcf9678c2ff6b7eaee6ff2edc0b11a4f484417ed604ee9bb7e92/Cython-0.29.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=772c13250aea33ac17eb042544b310f0dc3862bbde49b334f5c12f7d1b627476: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck behind a firewall or some other company proxy. That's it.
Depending on your company policy and whatever they've got running on their web or installed on your computer, the solution can be as a simple as connecting your computer through a mobile hotspot. That's what I've been doing for a while. Or bring your computer back home and run the whole thing from there.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm on a home network running Windows 10 on VMware Fusion.  I'm betting there is something in the VM settings that is problematic based on your note.  I'll poke around and report back!

Comment: @JeffH Did you figure out the exact problem here?

Comment: Not completely.  It wasn't firewall issue... as install was on a VM on my mac.  I just slicked the python install and re-installed from python.org deliverable, and was successful on the 2nd try.  Not sure what got hosed up with the certificate-ing.